# Suddenly Firebase events are not exported to Bigquery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

## Problem

- In our project, suddenly Firebase events are not exported to Bigquery. We want to fix it.

## Info

- From Feb 1st, 2021, we export Firebase events to Bigquery.
- Until Mar 1st, 2021, all the events are completely exported.
- However from Mar 2nd, 2021, only a few events are exported.

## Hypothesis

- In the Firebase console, I found the limitation of Bigquery. It's about to reach the limit. Is this problem caused because of the limit?
- [The warning in Firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G8tO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That indeed seems very likely, with 0.16GB left the project likely can't create enough space in the BigQuery sandbox for the new data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'll upgrade the BigQuery plan and try exporting the data again.